# Get the user role from Azure AD by Laravel azure ad oauth

Tags: php, laravel, azure, oauth, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get the role form Azure AD by using metrogistics/laravel-azure-ad-oauth  socialiate plugin.

I got the name and email and azure_id from the Azure. But I can't get the user role.

```
user: array:12 [
    "@odata.context" => "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity"
    "businessPhones" => []
    "displayName" => "Test4"
    "givenName" => "Test4"
    "jobTitle" => null
    "mail" => null
    "mobilePhone" => null
    "officeLocation" => null
    "preferredLanguage" => null
    "surname" => null
    "userPrincipalName" => "test4@xyz.com"
    "id" => "xyz"
  ]
```

It is possible to get the role from Azure.
My setup :

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U36rt.png)[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RmXL.png)[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwdkl.png)

Comment: Could you please what do your mean "role"?

Comment: I created the customer group and role in azure portal Like BDO, BDA.  and assigned the employee under the group and role.  I try to get that that while login

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, the defined AppRole will be returned in id_token. For more details, please refer to  the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens) and the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps)

[image]

Regarding how to get the user's id token, you can use Azure AD [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to implement it.  Here I use postman to acquire access_token and id_token:

[image]

And then I can get the id_token

[image]

By analyzing the id token, you can get the role of the user:

[image]

---

## Update

Regarding how to assign app role to user, please refer to the following steps

1. Declare app roles
   [image]
   [image]
2. Assign role to user

   a. In the **Azure Active Directory** pane, select **Enterprise applications** from the Azure Active Directory left-hand navigation menu.

   b. Select **All applications** to view a list of all your applications. If you do not see the application you want show up here, use the various filters at the top of the **All applications** list to restrict the list or scroll down the list to locate your application.

   c. assign role
   [image]

Comment: I checked this. In my token variable in role value.  I got only basic values above mentioned that.   I am using  https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize and https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token

Comment: @Arulraj If you want to get role value in id token, you need to assign role at first. Regarding how to assign, please refer to my update and the document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps

Comment: @Arulraj Could you please share the information of your id token?

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an [app role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps), and as the name suggests, they belong to an application. Merely seeking a user's object from Microsoft Graph wouldn't provide those.

And yes, as indicated in another answer, they will be provided to the application in an id_token after the user sign's in.

To fetch those independently of an app, use the [Get appRoleAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/approleassignment-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) Api.

Comment: It is beta version.  Is it passable in production URL. (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/)

Comment: Not yet, all /beta Apis will eventually move to production after a few months